# overload gestureRecognizerShouldBegin with UIPanGestureRecognizer in swift

Tags: swift, overloading, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pan gesture and I need to check when the gesture should begin. In objective-C you can use

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

and it possible to overload with UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

but in swift

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
```

it doesn't work and return

Overriding method with selector 'gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:' has incompatible type '(UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool'

How can I overload this method in swift?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to overload the method, you can do this instead :

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGesture = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        return ...
    }
    else {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove override, and don't forget to add the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate extension.

You can add it at the bottom of your class

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    // You class declaration
}

extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        //
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't really answered the question which was 'how to overload gestureRecognizerShouldBegin for PanGestures'